What is the difference between &mut Foo and *mut Foo?
In my Rust program, I'm getting back values of the form *mut Foo from a function written in C.
let x: *mut Foo = my_ffi_function();

What does this "*mut" notation even mean?
As far as I can tell, x is just a pointer to a mutable Foo struct, the same as &mut Foo.
This code compiles just fine:
    let mut s: String = String::new();
    let x: &mut String = &mut s;
    let y: *mut String = x;

What's difference between the two forms?

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/pointer.html#pointer-types

&mut Foo is a reference while *mut Foo is a pointer.
At runtime they are essentially the same thing; just an address to some other location in memory.
The difference is that references are checked by the compiler and must always be valid (point to an allocated, non-null, aligned, initialized value). To aid in that, a reference type also has an associated lifetime (annotated &'lifetime mut Foo) that is used by the compiler during the borrow checking step. This is the primary mechanism by which Rust ensures memory safety.
By contrast, the compiler does not check that pointers are valid. Pointers can be null, they can point to mis-aligned data, or to no value at all. Because of this, very little can be done with pointers in safe Rust and therefore access through the pointer must be done within an unsafe block. This is generally to be avoided since unsafe code is tricky to get right, but may be required in complex or performance sensitive scenarios (or frequently in FFI).
Your code block just demonstrates that references can be coerced into pointers.

Also pointers are commonly called "raw pointers".

*mut is a raw mutable pointer, which can be null, and can be manipulated in C-like ways, e.g. with casting, where &mut is a reference, guaranteed to not be null, and much more restricted.
In practice, most useful things you can do with *mut will require unsafe context, so if it's at all possible, avoid them, or failing that, narrow the unsafe scope (e.g. by wrapping your FFI interface calls with Rust functions that get the pointer, check it for validity, and convert it to a Rusty type, typically either a reference, Box-ed type, or an Option wrapping a reference to preserve "nullability" while providing the caller with a safe interface to protect against null pointer dereferencing, and allowing the caller to remain in safe Rust mode instead of discarding useful protections).
